# Android Fragment analog in Windows Phone

Tags: android, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I want to use something like Android Fragment in Windows Phone 8 application.

Description: in one of my pages I want to change PanoramaItem content if user not authorized. How would you solve that?

In Android I would just load another fragment to PanoramaItem view, but I got small experience with WP and do not know best practices for same problems.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what's going to be included in that particular item, I would probably have two different UIs declared in that panorama item

```
 <Grid x:Name="_Authorised" Visibility="Collapsed">
   <!-- Put all UI stuff here that will show when authorised -->
 </Grid>

 <Grid x:Name="_NotAuthorised" Visibility="Visible">
   <!-- Put all UI stuff here that will show when authorised -->
 </Grid>
```

Then in the OnNavigatedTo event (or whatever you feel appropriate)

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
 {
    if (UserIsAuthorised)
    {
       _NotAuthorised.Visibity = Visibility.Collapsed;
       _Authorised.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
 }
```